# C2DM - Device and third party server email accounts query

Tags: android, android-c2dm

Looking entirely from the user account perspective, are the following pointers to be followed for the C2DM push system to work?

1. Manually sign up on https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/signup and provide package name of my android app. consider emailId given is: foo@gmail.com
2. Programmatically Register from my android app using a email id, foo@gmail.com
3. From the third party application server send push notifications. Generate the authentication token using foo@gmail.com and pass****word.

My question is, is it mandatory to provide the same emailId in all the above places?

Comment: Yes (SO doesn't like 3 letter answers - but that's all I have to say: "Yes")

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Infact I am glad that the answer is "yes". I was wondering if the third party application server could register once and keep on sending the push notifications to devices which run the app registered with different accounts. I am gladly wrong anyways :)

Comment: They can, of course, send it out using your details (email + pass), but that would make them thieves. Only use trusted 3rd parties

Comment: I am getting confused again!! I am infact developing both the app and the third party application server.. so should i use a common email account or different accounts at the above mentioned places?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you're not trusting your 3rd party application server :) If it's you - you don't have to worry about anything. You should use a common account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes Please go though the links

https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/

Sender ID   An email account associated with the application's developer. The sender ID is used in the registration process to identify a Android application that is permitted to send messages to the device. This ID is typically role-based rather than being a personal account—- for example, my-app@gmail.com.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html

http://www.abolkog.com/portal/java-programming/117-android-push-notifications